# x86_64 android emulator on mac arm

Tags: android, docker, arm, x86-64, virtualization

I have got x86_64 android emulator prepared by some company and need to run this emulator on mac hosts with arm architecture. I am wondering if it is possible without preparing dedicated emulator for arm architecture.

I tried to use docker image with ubuntu and x86_64 architecture, then launch this emulator on docker image but there is an CPU acceleration issue during virtualization - "CPU acceleration status: /dev/kvm is not found".

I understand the error, KVM can't be found because mac host uses hyperkit for virtualization but I have no idea how to "force" using hyperkit and if it is possible at all. When I turn off acceleration emulator does't work.

Comment: If you want hardware virtualization, you're probably going to need native AArch64 android, not x86-64.  Rosetta 2 probably only works for user-space, not for full-system emulation inside a VM!  Also, you probably need native macOS software to use macOS virtualization APIs, not Linux's `/dev/kvm`, since I doubt macOS would emulate that even for an AArch64 Docker image.